# Showing that sets are Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm having a little trouble showing that some sets are Borel sets. Fundamentally, I think it's because, I'm not really entirely sure *what*  a Borel set is. The sets are:

$A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x\geq 0 , y\geq 0 , x^4 + y^4 <1 \} $

$B=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x\leq 0 , y\leq 0 , x^4 + y^4 <1 \} $

What I've been trying to do so far, is to write the set as a countable intersection (could do a union, but it seems it's easier to write it as an intersection?) of open and/or closed sets. I think that writing A out as:

$A=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^4+y^4<1\} \cap \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x\geq 0 , y\geq 0\} $

should do the trick.The first set is open because it can be written as $f^{-1}((-\infty , 1))$ (not sure what it's called in english) with $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4$ and $(-\infty , 1)$ is an open set, while the other set is closed because $g^{-1}((-\infty , 0])$ with $g(x,y)=(x,y)$ and $(-\infty , 0]$ is a closed set. Thus both sets are Borel sets and the countable intersection is then also a Borel set. At least, that's what I think..

Can anyone offer any help? I've no idea if it is any good what I've written - I'm really a fish out of water right now, haha.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

EDIT: Fixed typo.

Comment: In the definition of your $A, B$ you appear to be missing an inequality at the end.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. Completely forgot it, thanks :-) - fixed it now

Comment: With the typo corrected, that you have looks good to me. Did you mean for $A$ and $B$ to be the same set?

Comment: Haha, I'm really messing up right now - B is supposed to be like A, but with $x,y \leq 0$ - I'll fix it now, thanks!

Comment: In English $f^{-1}(A)$ is the *preimage* of set $A$ under $f$ (or "with respect to" $f$)

Comment: So, you wrote $A$ as the intersection of an open, and a closed set. Open and closed sets are Borel, and the Borel sets are closed under (countable, and so certainly finite) intersection, so you are done for $A$. For $B$, you write $B$ as the intersection of two closed sets, so it is closed, hence Borel. :D

Comment: One of the problems with the Borel sets, is that they come in many different kinds. If you want to show that every Borel set has a certain property, it is tempting to pick an arbitrary Borel $X$ and try to reason about it. This is, however, a tactical error. In general, you show that the collection of sets that satisfy the property you want contain a generating class for the Borel sets, and is closed under countable union and complement. Hence it is a $\sigma$-algebra containing all the Borel sets.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot! :-)

Comment: Actually, looking it over, should $\{(x,y)∈ℝ2:x^4+y^4<1\}$ be written as the preimage of $(-1,1) \in \mathbb{R}$ under the map $(x,y) \mapsto x^4+y^4$?

Answer (score 1):

With your approach you are on the right track.

[Borelsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) are sets that belong to the $\sigma$-algebra that is generated by open sets (or equivalently by closed sets). So they come in if the space has been equipped with a topology.

Consequently open sets and closed sets (the complements of open sets) are Borelsets, hence an intersection of an open and a closed set is a Borelset. This because a $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable intersections.